# In collect() terminal operation of Stream, what will happen if supplier is an immutable object like a String?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

`collect()` method of Stream is a mutable reduction. Based on Java Documenation:

> A mutable reduction operation accumulates input elements into a mutable result container, such as a Collection or StringBuilder, as it processes the elements in the stream.

I tried the following and it compiles without issue.

```
Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of("w", "o", "l", "f");
String word = stream1.collect(String::new, String::concat, String::concat);
System.out.println(word);
```

If the supplier is a StringBuffer, I view the collect operation as elements will be appended to the supplied StringBuffer.

How does mutable reduction works here since String is an immutable object? Will it be the same as reduce operation where a new object is created everytime the accumulator is implemented?

Comment: It doesn’t work. Did you ever try your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does mutable reduction works here since String is an immutable object?

It doesn't. When you run that you will get an empty String (the result of the `Supplier only`). The compiler can not enforce checking if the Supplier returns an immutable object, that is absolutely something it can not do. And since your container is immutable, updates to it are simply ignored. It's like doing:

```
String s = "abc";
s.concat("def"); // the result is ignored here
```

May be if you write that as a lambda it will make a lot more sense:

```
Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of("w", "o", "l", "f");
    String word = stream1.collect(
            String::new,
            (left, right) -> {
                left.concat(right); // result is ignored
            },
            String::concat);
```

On the other hand, when you use reduce, you are *forced* to return something:

```
String word = stream1.reduce(
            "",
            (x, y) -> {
                return x.concat(y);
            },
            (x, y) -> {
                return x.concat(y);
            });
```

Of course, you could still do:

```
String word = stream1.reduce(
            "",
            (x, y) -> {
                x.concat(y);
                return x; // kind of stupid, but you could
            },
            (x, y) -> {
                return x.concat(y);
            });
```

If you wanted to break it; but that is not the point.

Comment: The compiler *could* check if the Supplier returns an immutable object, it would only require some meta-information, similar to how other code audits work. It would be even simpler, if Java marked the obsolete `String()` constructor as deprecated. However, since the language does not forbid returning an immutable object (or doing stupid things in general), the best you could get, is a warning. Alternatively, there could be marker (annotations) for methods without side effects, to get a warning if a `[Bi]Consumer` has no effect.

Comment: @Holger how would it check immutable btw? Look at setters,`@Immutable`, etc... I dont even  understand how an annotation processor could enforce that :(

Comment: There is no requirement to actually enforce such a contract. E.g. Generics also work only as a compile-time check which can be broken. Likewise `@SafeVarargs` alters the compiler behavior, whereas current compilers can not really validate the declared safety. I’ve already seen warnings in IDEs which were based on the assumption that `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` have no side effects, which is reasonable, even if a particular implementation may have side effects, as that would be *another* error.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle / Java documentation:

***collect***

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, <R,? super T> accumulator, <R,R> combiner)
```

Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream. A mutable reduction is one in which the reduced value is a mutable result container, such as an ArrayList, and elements are incorporated by updating the state of the result rather than by replacing the result.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

***Mutable reduction***

A mutable reduction operation accumulates input elements into a mutable result container, such as a Collection or StringBuilder, as it processes the elements in the stream.
If we wanted to take a stream of strings and concatenate them into a single long string, we could achieve this with ordinary reduction:

> String concatenated = strings.reduce("", String::concat)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction

So, in a nutshell, it works because behind the scenes java is using a stringbuilder

Comment: That’s what I suspect though I cannot find the implementation in the Stream code in which it uses StringBuffer.

Comment: @PedroH I *wonder* what the result of the OP code would be if you run it... or see [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298568/1059372)

Comment: “such as a Collection or StringBuilder”  are *examples* of what a collector could use. It does nowhere allow the conclusion that the OP’s collector gets magically converted to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: How did you get to the conclusion that java is using a StringBuilder behind the scenes in the reduce operation?